# Is the order of operations maintained when a function is inlined in C by a compiler eg GCC?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-optimization

Consider the Following Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int f1() {
    printf("foo");
}

int f2() {
    int a;
}

int main() {
    int a = f1(), b = f2();

    printf("\n%d\n", a);
    printf("\n%d\n", b);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is as expected if the function were inlined:

```
foo
3

0
```

However, in the following case

```
#include <stdio.h>

int f() {
    printf("foo");
    int a;
}

int main() {
    int a = f();
    printf("\n%d\n", a);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
foo
3
```

and not

```
foo
0
```

even though the last statement returns nothing. 
I assumed that in definition of Howevver`f2()` since the function returned nothing, the compiler implicitly added a `return 0;` at the end. However why does this behaviour not occur with `f()`?

I usedd the following for compiling:

```sh
gcc -O0 a.c -o a.out
```

Comment: Your functions don't `return` anything, your code has undefined behavior.

Comment: Your assumption that there's an implicit `return 0` is wrong. The compiler should have warned you that you don't have any return statements.

Comment: Always compile with *warnings enabled*, and **do not** accept code until it *compiles without warning*. To enable warnings add `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` to your `gcc/clang` compile string (also consider adding `-Wshadow` to warn on shadowed variables). For **VS** (`cl.exe` on windows), use `/W3`. All other compilers will have similar options. Read and understand each warning -- then go fix it. They will identify any problems, and the exact line on which they occur. You can learn a lot by listening to what your compiler is telling you.

Comment: The implicit `return 0` is _only_ for `main`. All other functions need explicit returns on all paths (except if they "return" `void`).

Comment: @Mat: That is not actually a rule in the C standard.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: what part of that?

Comment: @Mat: The relevant rule in C 2018 is 6.9.1 12, which says the behavior is not defined by the C standard if a program attempts to use the value of a function call but execution of the function reached its terminating `}` (rather than going through a `return`). Thus, there are two times when a non-void function does not need to return a value: When the value is not used by the caller, and when the function does not return (e.g., when it calls `exit`). E.g., `int GetOrSet(int Choice, int Value) { if (Choice == Set) StoredValue = Value; else return StoredValue; }` is okay by the C standard.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Thanks, I stand corrected. (I'll stick with my version for beginners though :-).)

Answer (score 1):

> I assumed that in definition of Howevverf2() since the function returned nothing, the compiler implicitly added a return 0; at the end.

This is incorrect. Per the C standard, if a program attempts to use the value of a function call but the function does not use `return` to return a value, the behavior is not defined (C 2018 6.9.1 12). (Except `main` is special, a rule in 5.1.2.3 1 says it does return zero by default.)

> However why does this behaviour not occur with f()?

It has been observed that GCC appears to behave in this way: If there is no `return` statement in a non-void function, it returns the value of the last expression evaluated. I have not seen this documented, and it is not behavior you should rely upon. (In part because that rule is incomplete. For example, if the last expression has type `double` but the return type is `int`, we do not expect the rule would hold.)

In this case, that behavior causes `f` or `f1` to return three because the last expression evaluated in it is `printf("foo");`, and the value of a `printf` call is the number of characters printed, which in this case is three.